# Signature generated is too long to decode

Tags: java

I generated rsa keys this way:

> `openssl genrsa -out testkp.pem 2048 openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform PEM -nocrypt -in testkp.pem -out test_pkcs8.key openssl rsa -in keypair.pem -pubout -out test_publickey.crt`

And I read them this way:

```
@Test
  public void testJwt()
      throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, SignatureException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException {
    final KeyFactory keyPairGenerator = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    TreeSet<String> algorithms = new TreeSet<>();
    for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders())
      for (Service service : provider.getServices())
        if (service.getType().equals("Signature"))
          algorithms.add(service.getAlgorithm());
    for (String algorithm : algorithms)
      System.out.println(algorithm);

    PrivateKey key = getPrivateKeyFromFile("jwtTest/test_pkcs8.key");
    PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKeyFromFile("jwtTest/test_publickey.crt");

    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final Map<String, Object> header = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
    header.put("kid", "asdf");
    header.put("typ", "asdf");
    header.put("alg", "asdf");
    final String headerStr =  Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(header));

    final Map<String, Object> payload = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
    payload.put("iss", "asdf");
    payload.put("iat", "asdf");
    final String payloadStr = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(payload));

    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    signature.initSign(key);
    signature.update((headerStr + "." + payloadStr).getBytes());

    byte[] signatureBytes = signature.sign();

    final String signatureStr = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(signatureBytes);

    final String jwt = headerStr + "." + payloadStr + "." + signatureStr;

    log.info(String.format("Generated JWT: %s", jwt));

    String[] chunks = jwt.split("\\.");

    Assert.assertEquals(headerStr, chunks[0]);
    Assert.assertEquals(payloadStr, chunks[1]);
    Assert.assertEquals(signatureStr, chunks[2]);

    String h = new String(BaseEncoding.base64Url().omitPadding().decode(chunks[0]));
    String p = new String(BaseEncoding.base64Url().omitPadding().decode(chunks[1]));
    String sig = new String(BaseEncoding.base64Url().omitPadding().decode(chunks[2]));

    signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    signature.initVerify(publicKey);

    signature.update((headerStr + "." + payloadStr).getBytes());
    Assert.assertTrue(signature.verify(sig.getBytes()));
  }
```

but I get error:

```
Signature length not correct: got 469 but was expecting 256
java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 469 but was expecting 256
    at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:211)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1394)
    at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:771)
    ...
```

But it's confusing because I am using the same key pair to encrypt and decrypt. This should just work out of the box without mystery.

Mac 10.15.7
openjdk version "1.8.0_282"

Comment: The signature is a byte array but with "String sig = new String(BaseEncoding.base64Url().omitPadding().decode(chunks[2]))" you are trying to "build" a string - just consume the decoded (Base64Url encoded) string as input for your signature.verify function

Comment: Thanks for your response @MichaelFehr. I did the change you mentioned and I get java.lang.AssertionError on the verify. (1) why does storing it in a string cause it to be longer when converted back to bytes from string. (2) any idea why the verification could still be failing?